# Show live summation in Html Textbox helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a website using `asp.net mvc 4` and `jQuery 1.9.1` where user can get the summation automatically whenever typing to other textbox. But for some reason whenever I type to other textboxes I don't get any result in my `Total` textbox. Here are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toSum').each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $('.toSum').each(function () {
                if (this.value.length != 0) {
                    total += parseInt(this.value);
                }
            });
            $('#txtTotal').html(total);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane" id="AddFl" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SumManager", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Set Basic</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Flats.basic, new { @class="toSum" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Flats.basic)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Set Bill</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Flats.bill, new { @class="toSum" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Flats.bill)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Set Miscellaneous</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Flats.misc, new { @class="toSum" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Flats.misc)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Total</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Flats.total, new { id="txtTotal"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Flats.total)
        </div>                    
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" /></p>
    }
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code? How can I get the summation result instantly whenever user types on other textboxes? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toSum').on('keyup', function () {
        var total = 0;

        $('.toSum').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() && isFinite(parseInt($(this).val(), 10))) total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });

        $('#txtTotal').val(total);
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ddbkh58f/1/

Make the `total` textbox `readonly`, so that user cannot change its value

Answer (score 1):

Note that you do not need the initial `each()` call - the event will be applied to all elements within the matched set automatically. Also, you need to use `val()` to se the value of an `input`, not `html()`. Finally, you can improve the logic of checking for a value, by providing a default value using `||`. Try this:

```
$('.toSum').keyup(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.toSum').each(function () {
        total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
    });
    $('#txtTotal').val(total);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzddpep1/1/)

Comment: Showing `NaN` when adding alphabets inside textbox

Comment: @Tushar thanks, fixed. I put the validity check in the wrong place :)